# How to change permissions on a file on SD card

Tags: permissions

Changed the permissions on a file, `bsj`:

```
/media/cwh/BA70-05FE/swdev$ ls -al  ~/work/sw/swdev/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 cwh cwh 4096 Feb 28 22:21 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 cwh cwh 4096 Feb 28 22:21 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 cwh cwh 4048 Feb 28 22:21 bsj
/media/cwh/BA70-05FE/swdev$ chmod +x  ~/work/sw/swdev/bsj 
/media/cwh/BA70-05FE/swdev$ ls -al  ~/work/sw/swdev/
total 12
drwxrwxr-x 2 cwh cwh 4096 Feb 28 22:21 .
drwxrwxr-x 4 cwh cwh 4096 Feb 28 22:21 ..
-rwxr-xr-x 1 cwh cwh 4048 Feb 28 22:21 bsj
```

Tried same command on a file on an SD card:

```
/media/cwh/BA70-05FE/swdev$ ls -al
total 96
drwxr-xr-x 2 cwh cwh 32768 Feb 28 22:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 cwh cwh 32768 Dec 31  1969 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 cwh cwh  4048 Feb 28 22:17 bsj
/media/cwh/BA70-05FE/swdev$ chmod +x  bsj 
/media/cwh/BA70-05FE/swdev$ ls -al
total 96
drwxr-xr-x 2 cwh cwh 32768 Feb 28 22:17 .
drwxr-xr-x 4 cwh cwh 32768 Dec 31  1969 ..
-rw-r--r-- 1 cwh cwh  4048 Feb 28 22:17 bsj
```

Appears to have no effect.

Comment: It’s probably down to the filesystem. My guess is that the SD card is probably formatted in some FAT variant or other some other FS that doesn’t support the `chmod` permissions model either at all or in a compatible manner. What’s the output of `mount | grep BA70-05FE`?

Comment: IIRC there is  a mount option for the Fuse filesystem that sets all files as executable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are using a non-Unix file system (perhaps FAT32) on the SD card. Unix permissions do not work on those.

Answer (score 0):

FAT files systems do not support the execution flag.

You have use the `umask` or `fmask` option of `mount` to force the flags to the values you require. `umask` applies to both files and directories, `fmask` and `dmask` apply to files and directories respectively, so you often want to use `fmask`. This works like the `umask` you use in your shell scripts, typically:

```
rwx: 0
rw-: 1 
r-x: 2
r--: 3
---: 7
```

Remarks:

- the "user" and "group" in this case are those specified by the `uid` and `gid` mount options.
- this applies to all files on the filesystem
- there is also a "showexec" mount option that automatically sets the exec flag for things that look like DOS/Windows executables (*.exe, *.bat, *.com) but it overrides the execution flag from the mask, so make sure you are not using it.

For instance to mount a FAT filesystem and give you read+execute rights to all files, while making the files read-only for your group and unusable by everyone else:

```
mount -o rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,fmask=0237,dmask=0022,[other options] device mountpoint
```